# Issue adding description column to custom document library in VS2010

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-foundation, list-definition

I want to add a description column to my List definiton.  However when i do it the column does not show up on the EditForm dialog so that you can actually set the description.  Can someone look at the schema and tell me what i did wrong...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="DocumentList" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="DocumentList" BaseType="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0101">
        <Folder TargetName="Forms/Document" />
      </ContentTypeRef>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" />
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" Hidden="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInFileDlg="FALSE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Title;" Sealed="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title"></Field>
      <Field ID="{4b1bf6c6-4f39-45ac-acd5-16fe7a214e5e}" Type="Text" Name="TemplateUrl" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Template_Link;" XName="TemplateUrl" Filterable="TRUE" Sortable="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" FromBaseType="TRUE" PITarget="mso-infoPathSolution" PIAttribute="href" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="TemplateUrl"></Field>
      <Field ID="{cd1ecb9f-dd4e-4f29-ab9e-e9ff40048d64}" Type="Text" Name="xd_ProgID" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Html_File_Link;" XName="ProgID" Filterable="TRUE" Sortable="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" FromBaseType="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="xd_ProgID"></Field>
      <Field ID="{fbf29b2d-cae5-49aa-8e0a-29955b540122}" Type="Boolean" Group="_Hidden" Name="xd_Signature" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="xd_Signature" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Xml_signed;" XName="{FBF29B2D-CAE5-49aa-8E0A-29955B540122}" Filterable="TRUE" Sortable="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" FromBaseType="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE"></Field>
      <Field ID="{D815C45C-737A-4914-931E-B37452A73D54}" Type="Text" Name="Description" Hidden="FALSE" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInFileDlg="TRUE" DisplayName="Description" StaticName="Description"/>
      <Field ID="{e52012a0-51eb-4c0c-8dfb-9b8a0ebedcb6}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" Name="Combine" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Merge;" Filterable="FALSE" Sortable="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Combine">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" Key="Primary" />
          <FieldRef Name="EncodedAbsUrl" />
          <FieldRef Name="TemplateUrl" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{5d36727b-bcb2-47d2-a231-1f0bc63b7439}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" Name="RepairDocument" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Relink;" Filterable="FALSE" Sortable="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="RepairDocument">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" Key="Primary" />
          <FieldRef Name="ID" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </Field>
    </Fields>
    <Views>
      <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE" FreeForm="TRUE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkFilenameNoMenu"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Editor"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,Add_New_Document)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="MoreAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,MoreDocuments)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,All_Documents;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="True" MobileDefaultView="True" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png" Url="Forms/AllItems.aspx">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Description"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Modified"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Editor"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto2)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="2" Type="HTML" FileDialog="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,File_Dialog_View;" Hidden="TRUE" Path="filedlg.htm" ModerationType="Moderator">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="BaseName"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Editor" TextOnly="TRUE"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Modified" TextOnly="TRUE"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" Key="Primary" />
            <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="3" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Explorer_View;" TabularView="FALSE" Url="Forms/WebFldr.aspx" SetupPath="pages\webfldr.aspx" RequiresClientIntegration="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
        <ViewFields />
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="6" Type="HTML" TabularView="FALSE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Editor"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto2)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="7" AggregateView="TRUE" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Merge_Documents;" TabularView="FALSE" ToolbarTemplate="MergeToolBar" DefaultView="FALSE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png" Url="Forms/Combine.aspx" Hidden="TRUE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Combine"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Modified"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Editor"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto2)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="9" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Relink_Documents;" ToolbarTemplate="RelinkToolBar" TabularView="FALSE" DefaultView="FALSE" Url="Forms/repair.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png" Hidden="TRUE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkFilenameNoMenu"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="RepairDocument"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Modified"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Editor"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="ContentType"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="TemplateUrl"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto2)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
          </OrderBy>
          <Where>
            <Neq>
              <FieldRef Name="xd_Signature" />
              <Value Type="Boolean">1</Value>
            </Neq>
          </Where>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="40" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="assetLibTemp" DefaultView="FALSE" MobileView="FALSE" MobileDefaultView="FALSE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png" Url="Forms/Thumbnails.aspx" Hidden="TRUE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <RowLimit>20</RowLimit>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" Url="Forms/DispForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" Url="Forms/EditForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="Forms/Upload.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewFormDialog" Path="EditDlg.htm">
        <ListFormOpening>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript">
var frm = new OWSForm(]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <Switch>
              <Expr>
                <GetVar Name="HTMLFormName" />
              </Expr>
              <Case Value="">
                <HTML><![CDATA[OWSForm]]></HTML>
              </Case>
              <Default>
                <GetVar Name="HTMLFormName" />
              </Default>
            </Switch>
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[, false, ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <HttpVDir />
            <HTML>/_layouts/</HTML>
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[);
</script>
]]></HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript">]]></HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[ frm.dopt.chDateSep = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="29" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.dopt.chTimeSep = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="30" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.dopt.SetTimeFormat(]]></HTML>
          <ProjectProperty Select="Time24" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[); frm.dopt.SetDateOrder(]]></HTML>
          <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="33" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[); frm.dopt.SetDOW(]]></HTML>
          <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="4108" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[); frm.dopt.stAM = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="40" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.dopt.stPM = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="41" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.dopt.TimeMarkPosn = ]]></HTML>
          <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="4101" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.dopt.webTZOffsetMin = ]]></HTML>
          <ProjectProperty Select="TimeZoneBias" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[; ]]></HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[ frm.nopt.chDigSep = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="15" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.nopt.chDecimal = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="14" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.nopt.chMinus = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="81" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.nopt.iNegNumber = ]]></HTML>
          <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="4112" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[; frm.nopt.SetGrouping(]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <LocaleInfo LCTYPE="16" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[); ]]></HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
frm.stFieldPrefix = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>
            <FieldPrefix />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[;
frm.stImagesPath = ]]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote>/_layouts/images/</ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[;
frm.wBaseType = ]]></HTML>
          <ListProperty Select="BaseType" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[;
</script>]]></HTML>
          <Switch>
            <Expr>
              <GetVar Name="HTMLFormName" />
            </Expr>
            <Case Value="">
              <HTML><![CDATA[<form name="OWSForm" id="OWSForm" EncType="multipart/form-data" Action="]]></HTML>
              <HttpPath />
              <HTML><![CDATA[" Method=POST onSubmit="return false;">]]></HTML>
            </Case>
          </Switch>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
<input type="Hidden" name="_charset_" value="utf-8">
<input id="onetidCmd" type="Hidden" name="Cmd" value="Save">
<input id="onetidIsFormValid" type="hidden" name="IsFormValid">
<input id="onetidFormWasPosted" type="hidden" name="FormWasPosted">
<input id="MustUpdateForm" type="hidden" name="MustUpdateForm" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="NextID" id="NextID" value="-1">
<input type="hidden" name="NextUsing" id="NextUsing" value="]]></HTML>
          <GetVar Name="Source" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[">
]]></HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[<span id='part1'>]]></HTML>
          <Identity />
        </ListFormOpening>
        <ListFormBody>
          <HTML><![CDATA[<table border="0" cellpadding="2">
<script type="text/javascript">var _g_tp_fNewForm = true;</script>
]]></HTML>
          <Fields>
            <Switch>
              <Expr>
                <Property Select="Name" />
              </Expr>
              <Case Value="FileLeafRef">
                <SetVar Name="ShowField" Scope="Request">0</SetVar>
              </Case>
              <Default>
                <SetVar Name="ShowField" Scope="Request">1</SetVar>
                <HTML><![CDATA[<tr style="display:none"><th nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><nobr>]]></HTML>
                <Property Select="DisplayName" HTMLEncode="TRUE" AutoNewLine="TRUE" />
                <Switch>
                  <Expr>
                    <Property Select="Required" />
                  </Expr>
                  <Case Value="TRUE">
                    <HTML><![CDATA[<font color=red> *</font>]]></HTML>
                    <SetVar Scope="Request" Name="HasRequired">TRUE</SetVar>
                  </Case>
                  <Default>
                    <HTML><![CDATA[<font color=red></font>]]></HTML>
                  </Default>
                </Switch>
                <HTML><![CDATA[</nobr></th><td class="ms-formbody">]]></HTML>
                <Field />
                <Switch>
                  <Expr>
                    <Property Select="RichText" />
                  </Expr>
                  <Case Value="TRUE" />
                  <Default>
                    <Switch>
                      <Expr>
                        <Property Select="Type" />
                      </Expr>
                      <Case Value="Choice" />
                      <Case Value="MultiChoice" />
                      <Default>
                        <HTML><![CDATA[&#160;]]></HTML>
                        <Switch>
                          <Expr>
                            <Property Select="NoEditFormBreak" />
                          </Expr>
                          <Case Value="TRUE" />
                          <Default>
                            <HTML><![CDATA[<br>]]></HTML>
                          </Default>
                        </Switch>
                      </Default>
                    </Switch>
                  </Default>
                </Switch>
                <HTML><![CDATA[<span class="ms-formdescription">]]></HTML>
                <Property Select="Description" HTMLEncode="TRUE" AutoHyperLink="TRUE" AutoNewLine="TRUE" />
                <HTML><![CDATA[</span></td></tr>]]></HTML>
              </Default>
            </Switch>
          </Fields>
          <HTML><![CDATA[</table>]]></HTML>
          <Switch>
            <Expr>
              <GetVar Name="HasRequired" />
            </Expr>
            <Case Value="TRUE">
              <HTML><![CDATA[
          <table border="0" cellpadding="2">
          <tr>
            <td id="reqdFldTxt" class="ms-descriptiontext" colspan="2" height="150px" valign="top"><br><font color=red>*</font> 
             &#160;]]></HTML>
              <HTML HTMLEncode="TRUE">$Resources:core,webview_editdlg_required_field;</HTML>
              <HTML><![CDATA[
            </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          ]]></HTML>
            </Case>
          </Switch>
          <ContentTypes>
            <IfSubString>
              <Expr1>0x0120</Expr1>
              <Expr2>
                <Property Select="ID" />
              </Expr2>
              <Then>
                <HTML><![CDATA[
            <script type="text/javascript">
            _tp_rgctfld = new Array;
            _g_tp_rgcts.push(_tp_rgctfld);
            var fldct = frmCurrent.FindField("ContentType");
            if (fldct != null)
                fldct.AddChoice(]]></HTML>
                <ScriptQuote>
                  <Property Select="Name" />
                </ScriptQuote>
                <HTML><![CDATA[);
            </script>
            ]]></HTML>
              </Then>
              <Else>
                <HTML><![CDATA[
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var fldct = frmCurrent.FindField("ContentType");
            if (fldct != null)
                fldct.AddChoice(]]></HTML>
                <ScriptQuote>
                  <Property Select="Name" />
                </ScriptQuote>
                <HTML><![CDATA[);
            _tp_rgctfld = new Array;            
            ]]></HTML>
                <ForEach Select="FieldRefs/FieldRef">
                  <HTML>
                _tp_ctfld = new Object(null);
                _tp_ctfld.stName=</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="Name" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>;
                _tp_ctfld.fRequired = BoolFromString(</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="Required" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>);
                _tp_ctfld.fHidden = BoolFromString(</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="Hidden" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>);
                _tp_ctfld.fShowInNewForm = BoolFromString2(</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="ShowInNewForm" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>, true);
                _tp_ctfld.fShowInEditForm = BoolFromString2(</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="ShowInEditForm" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>, true);
                _tp_ctfld.fShowInFileDlg = BoolFromString2(</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="ShowInFileDlg" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>, true);                
                _tp_ctfld.fReadOnly = BoolFromString(</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="ReadOnly" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>);
                _tp_ctfld.stDisplay =</HTML>
                  <ScriptQuote>
                    <Property Select="DisplayName" />
                  </ScriptQuote>
                  <HTML>;</HTML>
                  <ForEach Select="Default">
                    <HTML>
                    _tp_ctfld.stDefault=</HTML>
                    <ScriptQuote>
                      <Property Select="." />
                    </ScriptQuote>
                    <HTML>;</HTML>
                  </ForEach>
                  <HTML>
                    _tp_rgctfld.push(_tp_ctfld);
                </HTML>
                </ForEach>
                <HTML><![CDATA[
            _g_tp_rgcts.push(_tp_rgctfld);
            </script>
            ]]></HTML>
              </Else>
            </IfSubString>
          </ContentTypes>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript">
var fldct = frmCurrent.FindField("ContentType");
if (fldct != null)
    fldct.BuildUI();
</script>
]]></HTML>
        </ListFormBody>
        <ListFormClosing>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
</span>]]></HTML>
          <Switch>
            <Expr>
              <GetVar Name="HTMLFormName" />
            </Expr>
            <Case Value="">
              <HTML><![CDATA[</form>]]></HTML>
            </Case>
          </Switch>
          <HTML><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
]]></HTML>
        </ListFormClosing>
      </Form>
    </Forms>
    <DefaultDescription>$Resources:core,camlidDc5;</DefaultDescription>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

Comment: It does show up on the new form? Are you selecting the content type when you edit the item? If you have multiple content types this could be a cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change ContentTypeRef to ContentType and specify fields you need to be in item's Content Type, like this:

```
<ContentTypes>
        <ContentType ID="0x0101">
            <Folder TargetName="Forms/Document" />
            <FieldRefs>
                <FieldRef Name="Description"/>
            </FieldRefs>
        </ContentType>
        <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" />
    </ContentTypes>
```

That should solve you issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifially need the two content types, you can remove this whole section:

```
<ContentTypes> 
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0101"> 
    <Folder TargetName="Forms/Document" /> 
  </ContentTypeRef> 
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" /> 
</ContentTypes>
```

Usually if you are adding custom columns you either add them to a custom content type and then reference the content type in the library schema -or- don't reference any content types and add the columns you want directly to the schema.